# hide an unrelated div when video playing

Tags: html, video, hide, playing

I'd like to hide my page's navigation when video is playing, just like the play button does.
Here's the script that succesfully hides the play button:

```
<script>
$('.vid').parent().click(function () {
if($(this).children(".vid").get(0).paused){
$(this).children(".vid").get(0).play();
$(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
}else{
$(this).children(".vid").get(0).pause();
$(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
}
});
</script>
```

And this script I tried to hide my navigation bar with:

```
<script>
function vidplay() {
var video = document.getElementById(".vid");
var button = document.getElementById(".playpause");
if (video.paused) {
video.play();
$(".navbar").hide();
</script>
```

[Here's link to my site](http://ropejumping.lv/#video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function;

```
$('.vid').parent().click(function () {
    $(".navbar").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your function and if statement

```js
<script>
function vidplay() {
  var video = document.getElementById(".vid");
  var button = document.getElementById(".playpause");
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    $(".navbar").hide();
  }
}
</script>
```